# How to restrict the users of your Python Module

Tags: python, security

I have a Python module which is meant to be used only by a consumer  say Jupyter. I need to find a way if the user invokes my module outside Jupyter , he should be blocked and  not allowed to use it.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Since this is `Python` you'll always be able to look at the source code and use/modify you program. It is possible, but more or less useless

Comment: @moritzg Correct but i think code obfuscation is not that great here. Can we add a layer of security to prevent users from using the module

Comment: @Nijesh in general, Python's guiding philosophy is that ["we are all consenting adults here"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html). Python does not make it easy to do what you want because it's considered unidiomatic.

Comment: Why would you prevent users to use your module how they see fit ?

Comment: Actually @PierceDarragh The aim is to keep track of who uses the module and  prevent the usage who doesn't belong to a group or has prior permission... Do u hve any ideas

Comment: @Nijesh I understand the problem; the philosophy still applies. There is no way (that I know of) to allow a user to access a resource through e.g. Jupyter but not outside of that environment, unless you directly modified Jupyter itself in some way. Further, I think it would be a bad idea and not terribly useful. Why would you want this functionality anyway?

Comment: @PierceDarragh Actually there is a requirement from the dumb product owners.on a related topic can we keep a check like a login system or an encryption mechanism which is validated by a combo to allow or block usgae of our module. I did design a service to do that but the need is to develop a solution that could be  shipped with module.

Comment: Hmm well... I haven't tested this, but you can try filesystem permissions. Create a user group for Jupyter and make the module and Jupyter owned by that group, and make the module permissions something like 600 or 700. Then set GUID on Jupyter so people who run it run the process with that group ID. Then you maybe will be able to access the module, but only while running Jupyter? No idea on Windows, and this may not work at all (on mobile or I'd try it real quick). Good luck!